# How do I configure Content Security Policy for use of ReCaptcha in Apache Superset?

Tags: apache-superset, recaptcha-v3, flask-appbuilder

I'm using the Superset in a Docker environment and I'm trying to get the AUTH_DB registration process to work but the Google reCaptcha box does not show when I access the registration site over a URL.

this i am trying but not showing google recaptcha in docker apache superset.
Error:
[image]

this is i am exepecting , flask app builder working fine like below image ,but i want to same as in apache super set
Exepected Result:
[image]

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D2QY.png)update the Google reCAPTCHA  in Domain use "Localhost" .
most of the people does "localhost" in the lowercase mistake.
instead of "localhost" use Uppercase "Localhost"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyrn4.png)